# Managing Very Large Vector File Geodatabases

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, fields-attributes, large-datasets, optimization

I am currently looking for ways to more effectively work with an extremely large 10,000,000 (+) vector features contained in a  file geodatabase.  Its just very cumbersome to work with in ArcGIS (v 10.2.2).

My current thought is to simply break the feature class in to 5 - 6 sub feature classes based upon OBJECT ID (e.g. 1 - 2,000,000; 2,000,001 - 4,000,000 and so on).  Since I don't want to break any features given it is topologically correct and clean. Then using model builder create a model to modify the attributes as necessary and simply rerun the model on each subsection and then append the sections back together, since I am not changing any of the geometries nor the attribute heading only the attribute records themselves.

Anyone have any other thoughts of how to deal with such large vector files?   Bottom line is I am having to reformat ~630,000,000 attributes - data restructuring, reformatting.  It currently can take up to 10 minutes just to reformat one attribute field.

Comment: It should be fine in ArcMap if it's indexed properly. Go to the feature class in Catalog, find the index hit delete then create (then apply) or use Add Spatial Index tool. What does reformatting involve? You can also use data caching.. we would need to know what it is that you're doing to the table that's taking so long, perhaps you could script that and go to lunch.

Comment: I did add a "Spatial Index" by subtype which seemed to help. Reformatting basically consists of converting  43 old features types into 63 new types. So what I initially did was merge a blank features class with the current data set.  That way I have a features class with the new (63) features attribute files and the 43 old ones. Then I can use a variety of if then or select cases statements to change and modify the old fields into the new fields.  The last step would be then to simply delete the old fields leaving only the new fields.

Comment: That does sound like something you could do in model builder, select a few for a sample and once it's right then run it on the whole dataset... when deleting fields you can remove more than one at once. Run the model when you go home, then it doesn't matter if it takes a few hours to run.

Comment: If reformatting involves field calculations, I'd suggest to forget about Filed Calculator and do calcs using da.updateCursor. Time saver really

Comment: The key thing about large and very large tables with spatial queries is to make sure that spatial fragmentation is as small as possible (spatial fragmentation occurs when neighboring rows in the table are distant from each other, causing an apparent random display order).  Defragmenting a badly fragmented table will make a whole lot more difference than splitting a very large fragmented table into many large fragmented tables.

Comment: @FelixIP, perhaps Jeff isn't comfortable with scripting but you're right arcpy.da cursors would be the way to go.. another thing that might help Jeff is to compress the gdb before moving on, Vince has a good point, if there are multiple edits against the table then it's bound to be badly fragmented in the database (internally, you wont see it), a compress operation puts it back to optimal.

Comment: I compress every night. I think I will just have to code it and let it run overnight.

Comment: @Vince Is there a link that you may be able to provide (perhaps in an answer) to anything written on detecting/addressing spatial defragmentation in file geodatabases?

Comment: @PolyGeo I've been preaching about spatial fragmentation for a long time (late 90's), but don't have a recent link. Unfortunately, compression actually *increases* spatial fragmentation.  It's going to be the weekend before I can draft something up.

Comment: Using da.updateCursor in python works great.